# Getting next Sunday's date

Tags: android, calendar

I'm using the following code to get the date of the upcoming Sunday. When my device language is English, it is working properly. But it is not when device language is changed to Spanish.

Eg : for English it gives 2015-11-22 but for Spanish it gives 2015-11-29.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
            calendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
            calendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
            calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

            // get start of this week in milliseconds
            calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);


            Date currentTime = calendar.getTime();
            date = dateFormat.format(currentTime);
```

Comment: Remember you're using TimeZone.getDefault(); where is your timezone?

Comment: It will use default timezone

Comment: try SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd" , Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: @bhargav it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration of your SimpleDateFormat to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd" , Locale.US);
```

It works for every language.

Comment: No change. Getting same 2015-11-29

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you get, set wrong day:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    // get start of this week in milliseconds
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.SUNDAY);
    Date currentTime = calendar.getTime();
    String date = dateFormat.format(currentTime);
```